# Span align center with img tag

Tags: html, css

I think it's so easy, but i'm stucked. What I want to do is centering the text "Some Text" according to the picture on the left. When I wrote the code used to center the div in the div below, the change did not take effect.
There is something I have not seen, something I missed. I'm glad you helped me.

```
margin:auto;
width:50%;
```

Now 
[image]

What i want

[image]

```css
.liTitle{
     padding:10px;
     background-color:#C4161A;
     color:white;
     cursor:pointer;
}
.liText{
  margin:auto;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="liTitle">
<img src="http://www.denizli.bel.tr/userfiles/image/icon/nobetcieczane.gif" width="24" height="24">
<span class="liText">Some Text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could just as easily achieve the same intended behaviour using standard `inline-block` display properties and `vertical-align` as demonstrated in the code snippet embedded below.

An advantage to this method is that it is not subject to the same legacy browser compatibility and support limitations that `flex-box` is, that is to say; *it'll work in IE 11*.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.liTitle {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #C4161A;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.liText {
  margin: auto;
  /* additional */
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Additional */

.liTitle img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="liTitle">
  <img src="http://www.denizli.bel.tr/userfiles/image/icon/nobetcieczane.gif" width="24" height="24">
  <span class="liText">Some Text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: "Flex" does not work well in IE browser. This solution is quite good except for "Flex". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

***This will work for you.***

I have used `display:flex;` to `.liTitle`

and also instead of `width:50%` i have used `flex:1;` for `.liText` and a little `padding-left` to proper gap between text and image.

**Note:** *if you want to know more about `flex` you can refer to this **[link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**.*

```css
.liTitle {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #C4161A;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
}

.liText {
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="liTitle">
  <img src="http://www.denizli.bel.tr/userfiles/image/icon/nobetcieczane.gif" width="24" height="24">
  <span class="liText">Some Text</span>
  <*emphasized text*/div>
```

Hope this was helpfull for you.

Comment: Ty for answer and explanation.

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL Glad I could help you. I hope this solved your issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the **Flexbox**:

```css
.liTitle {
  display: flex; /* displays children inline */
  align-items: center; /* vertical alignment / centering */
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #C4161A;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.liText {
  margin-left: 10px; /* modified / adjust to your needs */
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="liTitle">
  <img src="http://www.denizli.bel.tr/userfiles/image/icon/nobetcieczane.gif" width="24" height="24">
  <span class="liText">Some Text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Add this to your liTitle class

.liTitle {

```
    text-align: center;
```

}

Comment: When I add this code, both the picture and the text slide together.